# No SIGTERM before SIGKILL/shutdown with systemd on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, reboot, systemd, signal

I ran across this problem while I tried to [answer a question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39275997/4806820).

On shutdown, Ubuntu 12.04 sends `SIGTERM` to all processes and waits at most 10 seconds before killing them with `SIGKILL` (unless they terminated before). My answer on SO even contains a Python script that verifies that behaviour. The script is started in a terminal, sent to the background and than disowned by the terminal. When receiving `SIGTERM`, the script just keeps going and continuously prints to a file how long it has been running *after* receiving `SIGTERM`.

Ubuntu 16.04 however, the script is killed immediately on shutdown (no `SIGTERM` is logged).

I googled for a while, but I could not find anything useful. Has nobody ever come across that breaking change for the current LTS release?

Here is the script `signaltest.py`

```
import signal
import time

stopped = False

out = open('log.txt', 'w')

def stop(sig, frame):
    global stopped
    stopped = True
    out.write('caught SIGTERM\n')
    out.flush()

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, stop)

while not stopped:
    out.write('running\n')
    out.flush()
    time.sleep(1)

stop_time = time.time()
while True:
    out.write('%.4fs after stop\n' % (time.time() - stop_time))
    out.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

The script uses the file `log.txt` in the current directory for all output. It has a loop that prints 'running' every second. Receiving `SIGTERM` breaks the loop ans starts another loop which prints the seconds elapsed since receiving `SIGTERM`.

The script is run from a terminal a detached using `disown`:

```
python signaltest.py &
disown
```

**Just to be clear:** This is not a duplicate of [Ubuntu is not sending SIGTERM on shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786375/ubuntu-is-not-sending-sigterm-on-shutdown). The question is about desktop applications and the answers do not fit either.

Comment: Show how you run the code and do the logging. Is it logging to the systemd journal or a file? If the logging is going to the systemd journal, [it's possible some logging just before shutdown is being lost](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305926/how-to-log-systemd-watchdog-restarts/306497#306497), or the that the systemd journal is not using persistent storage. If the logging is going to a plain text file. That shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: @MarkStosberg I learned from [this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1352264) that `systemd` also sends `SIGHUP` on shutdown (at the same time as `SIGTERM`). This is something I did not suspect since the process was already detached. I already changed the answer on SO to ignore `SIGHUP`. That fixes the problem. I will probably post the answer myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

systemd (opposed to upstart in earlier Ubuntu verions) additionally sends SIGHUP on shutdown (and waits 90s instead of 10s before sending `SIGKILL`). I suggest to ignore `SIGHUP` or to handle `SIGTERM` and `SIGHUP` the same (idempotent) way.

The modified test script could be changed like this:

```
import signal
import time

stopped = False

out = open('log.txt', 'w')

def stop(sig, frame):
    global stopped
    stopped = True
    out.write('caught SIGTERM\n')
    out.flush()

def ignore(sig, frsma):
    out.write('ignoring signal %d\n' % sig)
    out.flush()

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, stop)
signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, ignore)

while not stopped:
    out.write('running\n')
    out.flush()
    time.sleep(1)

stop_time = time.time()
while True:
    out.write('%.4fs after stop\n' % (time.time() - stop_time))
    out.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```