# Is there a way to close all windows not minimised?

Tags: shortcut-keys, window

I would like a to use the command in a script I'm writing so, when it runs, all windows that are not minimised, whether they're in the front or the back, focused, or not, are closed.

Comment: @DKBose No I want to use the command in a script I'm writing.

Comment: See if https://askubuntu.com/questions/166279/how-can-i-close-all-opening-windows-with-a-script or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145752/how-to-kill-all-open-windows offer you any help.